# Why do I get an Unsupported Media Type on this request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making the below request from a WPF app to an MVC Core app that acts as an API:

```
var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", userName),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
});

////var content = new StringContent($"{{\"username\": {userName}, \"password\": {password}}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/Token", formContent);
var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var tw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenWrapper>(json);
return tw.Token;
```

When I inspect `resp` with a breakpoint, after the `PostAsync` call, I see a `415 - Unsupported Media Type` error. A breakpoint on the first line of the action isn't event hit, so I think the request isn't even reaching the controller.

The controller action looks like this:

```
  public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
 {
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", userName),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
    });

    ////var content = new StringContent($"{{\"username\": {userName}, \"password\": {password}}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/Token", formContent);
    var tempContent = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var tw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenWrapper>(json);
    return tw.Token;
}
```

I would expect `FormUrlEncodedContent` to imply the content type and work, as in the high number of examples I have seen like this. Why am I getting this 415 error?

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting the `Media Type`as below:

```
var content = new StringContent(formContent.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var result = await _client.PostAsync("http://example.com/api/Token", content);
```

Also [PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx) accepts parameters of `requestUri` and `content` , your code is the missing `Absolute` `requestUri`.

Comment: Assuming `_client` has a `BaseAddress` set, it's perfectly valid to use _"api/Token"_ in the post. But good points :)

Comment: @Mackan Yes. :) but if `BaseAddress` is not set, then you get this error: `An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.`